# How to upgrade/update or uninstall Azure Functions Core Tool in linux?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-functions-core-tools

I want to upgrade my Azure Functions Core Tools  in linux. However, it is so hard to find the straight forward documentation for that.

I followed this [Installation Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Clinux%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash) in Linux.

What I am trying to do now is to uninstall it then just install the new one. But I only found tutorials for uninstalling using VS Code. However, as I did not install Azure Functions Core Tools using VS code or npm this process also did not work for me.

Do you know how to properly upgrade it?

PS: I'm not sure whether upgrade or update is the right term as I am currently using v4.0.4704 and I just want to update it to v4.0.4785 or the latest version. I will also note the steps for my future reference. Thank you!

EDITED:

Btw, I run sudo npm uninstall -g func and this is the output up to date, audited 1 package in 426ms. After, that I run func --version and it is still in there.

Also, I just noticed that I have successfully installed this using npm.

```
sudo npm ls -g azure-functions-core-tools
/usr/local/lib └── azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.4865
```

But the version when I run func --version is different:

```
└─$ func --version 4.0.4704
```